# how connect to remote server in android 10

Tags: android

my android app connect to remote server(INTERNET) correctly on android 9 and bellow ,

but wont work in android 10.

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="esnmhy.mydream" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icons"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/fullScreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".loading"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    .
    .
    .

I use StringRequest(Request.Method.GET) in JAVA code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

You should removed this line from the android manifest file which is already there

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

and added this line

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

this in to application tag in manifest

```
<application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/icons"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:theme="@style/fullScreen"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
>
```