# Android app doesn't connect to peerjs server

Tags: android, peerjs

am working on a project to make android app stream camera to another app i made peerjs server to work with html and java website then used webview to use it in the app on the emulator everything is working but the problem is when i install the app on my android it doesn't connect to the peerjs server even when both my computer and phone are on the same wifi ( i don't see client connect like when i use the same app on the emulator ) i even tried using mobile hotspot and connect them .

The code am using to connect

```
peer = new peer (userId, {
host: '192.168.91.3',
port: '8000',
path: '/myapp'}
```

Thx in advance :)

Comment: The emulator runs in a local `10.x` sub-net ...not the LAN.

Comment: Am still learning bro I don't how peer servers work am just trying to connect my remote devices

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found a solution for my problem and I think your problem can be solved with this line:

android:usesClearTextTraffic="true"

add this to your Manifest.xml in application tag.

I found my answer in this two sites:
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/faq/uses-clear-text-traffic/,
[how connect to remote server in android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261518/how-connect-to-remote-server-in-android-10)